# Is there any way to bold or italicize individual words in Bixby paragraph text?

Tags: bixby

I don't see any way to **emphasize** an individual *word or phrase* using Bixby's text styling and font features. Is this correct?

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.single-line.text.style

Answer (score 0):

I've double checked with our Bixby View Team, unfortunately, specific syntax such as bold or italics are not supported at the moment.

All the available style are listed in [Fonts Reference of design guide](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/resources.fonts). And please note that the style applies to the entire string of a `template` or the entire string of a `slot` from a card component.

If this feature is critical to your capsule development, I would recommend that you raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) in our community. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.